# Preloaded Android application with .so library file cannot be upgraded

Tags: android, preload

I work for an operator, and we preload applications on Android phones.

However, some preloaded applications, once upgraded from Market, crash.

The problem is this:
- the application contains a .so library file
- in order to preload the complete application on a phone, the .so library file has to be placed separately into the lib directory (/system/lib/libXXXXjni.so)
- when the preloaded application is upgraded from Market and run, instead of the .so library file in the new APK being found, the older preloaded .so file is found first - causing a crash, because the two .so fiels have differing contents

Does anyone have a suggested work-around, or knowledge of the library-searching algorthim which may help me solve this?

One possible solution might be to simply rename the library file, but is that enough?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

When you preload, try putting the applications library in:
/data/data/com.package.foobar/lib/libXXXXjni.so

Renaming the library would work. Possibly using the app's version number as the name of the .so file. The build becomes more complicated though.

Comment: For any kind of preload situation, wouldn't the device have to have root access to do a rename of a file in that /data/data location?

Comment: I was thinking that the library gets a new name in the upgraded version. The renaming would take place on the developer's machine (and in the System.loadLibrary(...) call in the code.) Best I think is preloading the library in the app's lib directory instead of /system/lib.